# How do I update a list in flutter app everytime a new child is added in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I have a flutter application in which I need to update the list in realtime every time a new child is added to the database. I have tried looking for it everywhere but nothing is working. Please provide an example code to implement it.

Comment: put some code of what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](https://grokonez.com/flutter/flutter-firebase-database-example-firebase-database-crud-listview) post about CRUD operations with firebase. What you are looking for is basically the Read part. Using a stream to listen to the changes made in your firebase reference.